# How to change the vue slot machine wheels direction?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am basically following the code of this https://jsfiddle.net/floorish/2Lb2v5k0/ . I successfully changed the direction of wheels from (upward to downward) to (downward to upward) by changing the line `const pos = -1 * Math.floor((offset + opt.finalPos) % opt.height)` to `const pos = 1 * Math.floor((offset - opt.finalPos) % opt.height)` but it is skipping some items in the start and working fine the in end.